# The temporary folder to delete for clean starting of IBM WAS

Tags: websphere

I wonder if someone could let me know the temp folder that IBM WebSphere server creates when running. I have some problem during starting WAS and try to delete that folder so there is no mess left. It is WAS 8

Answer (score 0):

profile_root example:

> C:/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profile_name/profile_root/config/temp
>   C:/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profile_name/profile_root/wstemp
>   C:/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profile_name/profile_root/temp
>
> Be careful in deleting any temporary, cache and log files in WebSphere
>   Application Server.   Before making any changes to the environment ,
>   take a backup of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

My solution works on WAS 8.5

1. Stop the WebSphere server JVM (and any other JVMs (NodeAgent AppServers running under that node profile)
2. If the application appears deployed on the server, remove it.
3. Remove the following directories: \temp, \wstemp, and \config\temp. (DO NOT REMOVE THE CONFIG DIRETORY, JUST CONFIG\TEMP)
4. Search the name of your project inside websphere server directory and remove them if they are in \config\cell<node>\
5. From the bin directory, run as administrator: clearClassCache.bat osgiCfgInit.bat Note, Clearing OSGi Cache requires all java instances using the cache to be stopped. More details in technote  http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21607887
6. Start the server (and application).